# WCF Exception Question

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

We have a WCF service. I used to deploy it with a config file which is used for all builds. It used to work fine. Today when I used the same file I am getting the following exception.

> Unrecognized ServiceSettings attribute ConfigurationFile.

Nothing is changed in the config file. Any idea what could be the reason for this error message?

It is hosted in windows service.

Why does it say ConfigurationFile="C:\KKE\AppName\Service\MyServiceHost.config" is invalid entry?

```
<services>
      <service name="AccessManager" type="Access.ServiceLayer.AccessManager, Access.ServiceLayer" ApplicationBase="C:\KKE\AppName\Service" ConfigurationFile="C:\KKE\AppName\Service\MyServiceHost.config">
        <failureProtection retryLimit="3" retryWaitPeriod="30" retryTimePeriod="300" />
      </service>
```

Comment: Maybe the version of .NET which your service is running on?

Comment: Any chance you could post your `configSection` definition and your `ConfigurationFile` sections from your config file?

Comment: Compare with  or replace by a backup from when it still worked.

Comment: Is there a ServiceSettings section in your config file?

Comment: Posted a portion from the file. Why does it say ConfigurationFile="C:\KKE\AppName\Service\MyServiceHost.config" is invalid entry?